# is vs. are... which is correct?

Tags: word-usage

I'm confused, perhaps unnecessarily by which term to use:

> What programs ***is*** company X involved in?

OR

> What programs ***are*** company X involved in?

Comment: You want to use *is* because it is the company (singular) which is *involved*. The programs *are*, say, socially-conscious, but the *company is* involved. If you want to explore this further, our sister site [ELL.se] is **awesome** for this kind of question.

Comment: You want it to be *is* if you are in America. You want it to be either if you are elsewhere. You want it to be *are* if you are elsewhere still.

Comment: Is this a case of subject-verb inversion?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I felt like an idiot asking this; however, the more I thought about it, the more confused I became.